# Firefox extension content script cannot request XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

According to the [Firefox Content Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#XHR_and_Fetch),the XMLHttpRequset can be used.

I have tried both XMLHttpRequest and Api Fectch.It only responses with error message.
I already disable CORS on the server.It still dosen't work.

I run Django local server on the computer.

This is the code:

```
function getWord(word){
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${word}/",true);
   req.onload = function(){
      console.log("done");
   }
   req.onerror = function(){
      console.log("error : ",this.error);
   }
   req.send();
```

Console error:

`error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, … }`

It work on other files(Not extension).

Comment: Are you sure that your URL resolves normally, and that the `word` variable is populated correctly? Check your browser's network tab.

Comment: I'll edit.The `word` is the parameter of the function.

Comment: that error isn't helpful at all - what is the actual error itself, you seem to have `...` instead of the useful message ... `I already disable CORS` - why?

Comment: It shows only that error.If I don't put the `req.onerror` It dosen't show anything.

Comment: Are you sure you have `webRequest` in your extension's permissions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions

Comment: @squgeim,you are right.I didn't put the permission in the manifest file.Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem solve

The problem is that I forgot to set the permission in the manifest.json.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions